# Snapshot state is 'running' even after cancelling the upload task in AngularFire2's Firebase Storage

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-storage, angularfire2

I am using `AngularFire2` to upload a file in `Firebase Storage`:

```
this.task = this.storage.upload(uploadPath, file);

this.task.snapshotChanges()
            .subscribe(snapshot => {
                this.snapshot = snapshot;
            });
```

It works as expected, however, when I cancel the `task` through the `cancel()` method, `snapshot` doesn't change, thus `state` is `running`, instead of `cancelled`. Why is that?

```
this.task.cancel();
// this.snapshot.state === 'running', not 'cancelled'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to be a real bug

The last event is not emitted on the snapshotChanges() however it will be emitted in the .then() promise

```
this._task.snapshotChanges()
  .subscribe(snapshot => {
    this.snapshot = snapshot; // To get updates on progress
  });
this._task.then(snapshot => {
  this.snapshot = snapshot; // To know when it is done
}).catch(snapshot => {
  this.snapshot = this._task.task.snapshot; // To know whenever there is an error/cancel from user
});
```

Comment: so were you able to cancel the upload in progress?